# Link shared library from another directory

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, ldd

I am building `foo.so` and that depends on `bar.so`. They will both be installed in the same location `/some/lib`, with the `RUNPATH` set appropriately to `/some/lib`. But they are built from different directories.

I'm trying to build them like:

```
cd /tmp/bar
gcc -o bar.o -c bar.c
ld -Bshareable -o bar.so bar.o
cd /tmp/foo
gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c
ld -Bshareable -rpath /some/libs -o foo.so foo.o ../bar/bar.so
ldd foo.so
```

But the problem is that `ldd` shows `../bar/bar.so`. I can fix it by doing:

```
cd /tmp/bar
gcc -o bar.o -c bar.c
ld -Bshareable -o bar.so bar.o
cd /tmp/foo
gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c
cp ../bar/bar.so .
ld -Bshareable -rpath /some/lib -o foo.so foo.o bar.so
ldd foo.so
```

Now the `ldd` just show plain `bar.so`, which is right. But is there a better way that doesn't require copying or symlinking `bar.so` just for the link step?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
ld -Bshareable -rpath /some/lib -L../bar -o foo.so foo.o -l:bar.so
```

works without needing to copy `bar.so` to the current directory.